# File path can't open with token in mod header - unable to open S3 bucket file

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I've created a REST API app in Django REST. Through it you can upload files to a server, tag them etc.

I have connected an S3 AWS bucket as the storage system. The problem is. The app has a token authentication set up. So you get to upload files only if authenticated. BUT when you want to open the file (click on the json link in the displayed data), you have to turn off your mod header with the authentication token, because otherwise it messes up with the opening and tries to input the token in constantly. And this is the better option, for it to at least open like that I had to make the bucket completely public.

So the reality is, you post files, with the token authentication on. You can access the api only with the auth token on. But whenever you would want to open a file, you have to turn off the mod header which results in you checking and unchecking the mod header token constantly like an idiot if you want to browse api + open files. Plus because the bucket is public, anybody could see your files... not ideal

REST API Serialized data (this is after you post a file)

```
{
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Pokus",
    "date_uploaded": "2020-04-07T20:26:24.182297Z",
    "file": "https://asko-artinii-test.s3.amazonaws.com/user-files/Screenshot_2020-04-07_at_16.13.57.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAW2ZGA6SZX2DN2D5O%2F20200407%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200407T211228Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2025712679ed2c37e535e3bf95ef04934fde2becd72f4aab47ad8b024f0d9120",
    "tag": [
        2
    ],
    "visibility": "PRV",
    "description": "ss"
},
```

You see it's first of all crazy long, and second of all *not* functioning with the mod header with your token on.

This is the error you get (with the token):

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>
Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified
</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>Token 0a411ccab5176938b852d207b2eef676eb52b186</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>10F00C90B358418A</RequestId>
<HostId>
dmWUqRvjxfEaOh0Mu1ISzVT4PYTxy3Bu5S4R8+wtIT+BX70XZXnomlvnDF2bpu0Ba0dAWVxwQ14=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a way to make it ignore the mod header token? somewhere in the s3 bucket configs? I mind you it's all public at this point so no restriction there.
2. Is there a way to make it not public and still somehow work? I have a normal Django app where I didn't have to make it public and it still worked (User could see their pictures) and I didn't have to set up anything special for it.
3. Is there simply a better way? I don't want to have the bucket public at all.

these are my `settings.py`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_ARTTEST')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ARTTEST')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME_ARTTEST')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-central-1"

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: Very helpful ...